# Flutter CustomPainter Resize

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-canvas, custom-painter

So I've been trying to resize a `CustomPainter` and keep the look as if it was pixel art, but I haven't been able to make it.

```dart
// for example, I have this widget, that sets an specific size to a CustomPainter,
// in this case width and height are 16

         SizedBox(
            width: width*scaleFactor,
            height: height*scaleFactor,
            child: ClipRect(
              child: CustomPaint(
                size: Size(width*scaleFactor, height*scaleFactor),
                painter: MyCustomPainter(scaleFactor),
              ),
            ),
          );

// and this would be the custom Painter

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{

final double scaleFactor;
  MyCustomPainter(this.scaleFactor);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor);
    canvas.drawPaint(Paint()..color = Colors.white70);
    canvas.drawLine(const Offset(4,4), const Offset(12,12), Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..isAntiAlias = false);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;

}
```

if I set the scaleFactor to 1, I get the results I want of course

[image: customPainter_scale_1]

and if I change the scaleFactor I get something like this:

[image]

but what I would actually want it to like like is like this:

[image]

I've even tried with a `Transform.scale` widget (not even changing `FilterQuality` helps) and even setting a scale matrix inside the canvas with `canvas.transform()` but I haven't got any good results.